# Why I've got Permission Denied when using sudo with pipe?

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, grep, sudo

When I execute this command:

```
sudo -u www-data grep -a 't=' /var/www/temp/w1_slave | cut -f2 -d= > /var/www/temp/temp.txt
```

I have error:

> Permission Denied

What I am doing wrong? User `www-data` is owner of `/var/www/temp/temp.txt` and also this user is owner of `/var/www/temp/w1_slave` and entire `/var/www` directory.

Command:

```
sudo -u www-data grep -a 't=' /var/www/temp/w1_slave | cut -f2 -d=
```

works fine and also I can modify file`/var/www/temp/temp.txt` by this user.

Here is `ls -lh`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    5 paź 21 20:46 temp.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 4,0K paź 21 21:01 w1_slave
```

I'm trying to copy remote file by:

```
scp osmc@10.100.10.10:/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000006140194/w1_slave /var/www/temp
```

and store the output into the variable from that file in another file. Can I do grep from remote server without copying that file locally?

Comment: Asking for command-line is better at http://superuser.com/, as it's not real programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `sudo`, it relates only to the first command, not the second  after the pipe (`|`), in the same way the last redirect (`>`) doesn't have the right credentials to create the file.

If you need both commands (including redirect) to run with sudo access, then you've to wrap them with shell, for example:

```
sudo -u www-data sh -c "grep -a 't=' /var/www/temp/w1_slave | cut -f2 -d= > /var/www/temp/temp.txt"
```

or use `sudo tee`:

```
sudo -u www-data grep -a 't=' /var/www/temp/w1_slave | cut -f2 -d= | sudo tee /var/www/temp/temp.txt
```

which will add content into the file (and at the same prints it). If you don't want to print it, redirect the standard output to `> /dev/null`.

---

To `grep` remote file without copying (which `scp` does), use `ssh` instead. Just run the same command that you normally would run, but prefix with `ssh user@host` then assign it to the variable, for example:

```
FOO=$(ssh osmc@10.100.10.10 "command")
```

This assumes you've the right SSH keys setup, so it won't ask you for the password.

To see if that would work, first of all check the command manually by:

```
ssh osmc@10.100.10.10 "whoami"
ssh osmc@10.100.10.10 "sudo -u www-data whoami"
```

For debugging, add `-x` to your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) or add multiple `-v` to your ssh.

Comment: Thanks, it works well. Can You help me with second question?

Comment: @user1815887 Added, let me know if that's clear enough or need further explanation.

Comment: Should that command works?

`sudo -u www-data sh -c "FOO=$(ssh osmc@10.100.10.10 "grep -a 't=' /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000006140194/w1_slave | cut -f2 -d=") > /var/www/temp/temp.txt"`

Comment: I just done that using:

`sudo -u www-data sh -c "FOO=$(ssh -vv osmc@10.100.10.10 "grep -a 't=' /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000006140194/w1_slave | cut -f2 -d=") | echo $FOO >> /var/www/temp/temp.txt"`

Thanks a lot for help!

But there is another problem - i need to only store actual variable, and this command appends new to existing file.

Comment: @user1815887 So don't use `sudo tee` at all, it'll automatically redirects the output to the variable. You don't need any `temp.txt`. Depending what is your main, either store it into variable, or store it in temporary file.

Comment: I need this file to store variable into it. Temp in this case doesnt mean temporary - its temperature. In specific time i need to store variable into that file, and later (i dont know specific time) use it in another way. There can be only one variable after executing command in that file.

Comment: @user1815887 Your example shows that you're piping variable assignment into echo, which is not valid, you just separating different commands by `;`. But I think you don't need variable at all, just redirect to the file like: `ssh user@host 'grep foo /path/srcfile | cut' | sudo tee /path/dstfile`, unless you want to compare if it's not empty.